# Creation of TypeVariable instances

Tags: java, reflection, type-variables

The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) of `TypeVariable` is really confusing, firstly it specifies that :

> A type variable is created the first time it is needed by a reflective method

and

> Repeated creation of a type variable has no effect

So what I understand is that there's only one instance of `TypeVariable` representing a type variable at run-time, for example :

```
class A<T> {}
```

We will have one instance of `Type Variable` that represent `T` at run-time.

But the documentation adds :

> Multiple objects may be instantiated at run-time to represent a given type variable. Even though a type variable is created only once, this does not imply any requirement to cache instances representing the type variable. However, all instances representing a type variable must be equal() to each other

From the above quotation I understand that there are two kinds of instantiation :

1. Creation of type variable (Which i don't understand)
2. Instantiation of multiple instances representing type variable

Can anyone please explain what the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
class Ideone<T> {
  List<T> getList() { ... }
}
```

It is saying that the type variables representing the `<T>` on the class and the `<T>` on the method aren't necessarily the same instance:

```
TypeVariable onClass = Ideone.class.getTypeParameters()[0];
TypeVariable onMethod = Ideone.class.getDeclaredMethod("getList").getReturnType().getTypeParameters()[0];

System.out.println(onClass == onMethod);
```

Prints `false`, even though they're representing the same type variable.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/wBnhqB)

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, so when the third quotation says `Even though a type variable is created only once` it has the same meaning as `Even though the instance representing a type variable is created only once` ?

Comment: "Even though the instance representing a type variable is created only once" isn't correct. "Even though a type variable is created only once" means "even though only one type variable is declared".

Comment: So the word creation means the number of declarations of type variable that exist in the code ?

Comment: Thanks really for your help.

Comment: I think this is a wrong example, the return type is List<T>, but the class is Ideone<T>. Although both TypeVariable instance's names are "T", but they are totally different TypeVariable instance (genericDeclaration is different), that's the reason they are not the same, if you use onClass.equal(onMethod), it still return false. Check my alternative answer in below.

Comment: The fact that one is `Ideone<T>` and the other is List<T>` is quite irrelevant. This is taking about usages of the *type variable*, T, not the types in which that variable is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the source code of TypeVariableImpl in package sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects, the equal method is defined as:

```
  158       public boolean equals(Object o) {
  159           if (o instanceof TypeVariable) {
  160               TypeVariable that = (TypeVariable) o;
  161   
  162               GenericDeclaration thatDecl = that.getGenericDeclaration();
  163               String thatName = that.getName();
  164   
  165               return
  166                   (genericDeclaration == null ?
  167                    thatDecl == null :
  168                    genericDeclaration.equals(thatDecl)) &&
  169                   (name == null ?
  170                    thatName == null :
  171                    name.equals(thatName));
  172   
  173           } else
  174               return false;
  175       }
```

So It look into declaration first, meaning from where you get this TypeVariable instance (the class where you get the TypeVariable instance), then the name. If both of them are the same, they are equal.

My understanding is "Multiple objects **may** be instantiated at run-time to represent a given type variable." It's based on implementation. I run following code with jdk1.7, results show that the TypeVariable instance from the return type of the method is the same instance got from the class declaration:

```
public class TestMain
{
      public interface MyInterfaceC<A,B,c> {  
      }  

      public class Test<A,B> implements MyInterfaceC<A,B,Integer> {
          public MyInterfaceC<A,B,Integer> returnThis() {
              return null;
          }
      }

      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  

      Type[] ts = Test.class.getGenericInterfaces();
      TypeVariable t1 = (TypeVariable)(((ParameterizedType)ts[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);

      TypeVariable[] cmp = MyInterfaceC.class.getTypeParameters();

      Type mtdRet = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod( "returnThis" ).getGenericReturnType();
      Type[] mtdRaw = ((ParameterizedType)mtdRet).getActualTypeArguments();
      TypeVariable mtd = (TypeVariable)mtdRaw[0];

      System.out.println( "cmp[0].equal(mtd)?" + cmp[0].equals( mtd ) + ", cmp[0]==mtd? " + (cmp[0]==mtd) );
      System.out.println( "mtd.equal(t1)?" + mtd.equals( t1 ) + ", mtd==t1? " + (mtd==t1) );
      }
}
```